# How to make custom metabox fields duplicatable?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, repeat, meta-boxes

I am now currently coding a plugin for the WordPress admin. It's about custom meta boxes. I would like to create a slideshow plugin, just for learning a lot of coding.

I have created one metabox, that contains an image upload and a text input field. *(see picture bellow)*

[image: Here is the metabox with the fields]

So on, I can save the fields, so I can upload an image and set an capton to it inside the text field. When I save the post/page inside WordPress it will save the values for me in my database. That's fine!

Now I would like to expand the code, through the user possibility to add and remove fields, like, repeatable field.
As you can see in the image above, I have created the add new slide button, I have also code some javascript for get it work, but this doesn't work correctly.

So my question to you is, what's the best way to create dynamically fields?
I am now using the clone function in javascript, to clone the fields, but only the default row will work.

I've been a few weeks with it and couldn't find a solution so far.

Some code:
This is the [code of my metabox](http://snippi.com/s/ri36qw3) created with PHP
This is the [jQuery / Javascript](http://snippi.com/s/adtzeoi) that I'm using now

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've [answered many Questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12615+repeatable) regarding this topic in WordPress StackExchange.
It is called *Repeatable Fields*.

But basically these are the needed resources:

- [Create more Meta Boxes as needed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/19852/12615) - WPSE Q&A
- [Repeatable Custom Fields in a Metabox](https://gist.github.com/1593065) - Gist

  > ```
  > /**
  >  * Repeatable Custom Fields in a Metabox
  >  * Author: Helen Hou-Sandi
  >  *
  >  * From a bespoke system, so currently not modular - will fix soon
  >  * Note that this particular metadata is saved as one multidimensional array (serialized)
  >  */
  > ```
- [Repeatable Custom Fields in a Metabox](https://gist.github.com/2057532) - Another Gist example, no description given

Comment: Thank you for your respond, I will look to the files. One question, what's the difference between those source files and which one can you recommend me?

Comment: Probably, one of the Gists, but play with them all ;)

Comment: Is it possible to add repeatable fields into WordPress setting pages? e.g. wp-admin/options-general.php?page=your_plugin