# Duplicate text field with jQuery and store in DB in Wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

This time I really require assistance in creating a multiple text fields and save them in database. For now I know how create additional text fields with 'add' link, but if I create, let's say, 10 text fields and populate them with text only the first one is added to database, other 9 not, and I need to know why?? (Probably I need to create a php function, which catches every click on 'Add' button and crates new array???)

1.array storing data:

```
array( "name" => "TEST",
    "type" => "section"),
array( "type" => "open"),

        array( "name" => "Button:",
            "desc" => "Another text button",
            "id" => $shortname."_testbutton",
            "type" => "textbox",
            "std" => ""),

array( "name" => "TEST2",
    "type" => "section2"),

array( "type" => "close"),
```

2.Text fields:

```
<h2>
    <a href="#" id="addbutton">Add</a>
</h2>
<div id="textfields">
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"></label>
    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" size="20" name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" value="<?php if ( get_settings( $value['id'] ) != "") { echo stripslashes(get_settings( $value['id'])  ); } else { echo $value['std']; } ?>" placeholder="Input Value" />
    </p>
</div>
```

3.jQuery

```
jQuery(function($) {
        var scntDiv = $('#textfields');
        var i = $('#textfields p').size() + 1;

        $('#addbutton').live('click', function() {
                $('<p><label for="test_testbutton"></label><input type="text" id="test_testbutton" size="20" name="test_testbutton_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /> <a href="#" id="removebutton">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
        });

        $('#removebutton').live('click', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});
```

PS. That's for Wordpress theme options page.

**EDIT!!!**

I managed to create functioning loop which gets the number of created textfields, gets their values, puts everything back into textfields and preserves everything. I changed jQuery a bit:

```
name="test_testbutton_' + i +'"
```

to:

```
name="test_testbutton[]"
```

as Adam Erstelle suggested, and I looped everything in:

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['test_testbutton']) && is_array($_REQUEST['test_testbutton'])) {
$numbers = $_REQUEST['test_testbutton'];
foreach ($numbers as $number) {?>
<input type="text" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" size="20" name="test_testbutton[]" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" placeholder="Input Value" /><a href="#" id="removebutton">Remove</a> <?php
}}?>
```

**Now Everything is stored in array as it supposed to be, but I have a problem with feching textfields' values to frontend and display them...????**

Comment: First off `live` was long ago deprecated, you should start using `on` instead.  Second, where you're PHP form submit handler?

Comment: I think you're looking for *repeatable fields*, see [How to make custom metabox fields duplicatable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14537690/1287812) and [custom image fields in wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14445904/1287812) (this one has a full plugin code)

Comment: @brasofilo - probably it would work as I only knew how to change certain function elements to fit in theme options admin page, not post settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is create an HTML array of values.

instead of

```
name="test_testbutton_' + i +'"
```

try

```
name="test_testbutton[]"
```

On the PHP side, $_POST['test_testbutton'] should an array of values. You can then work with this array as you need (keeping in mind that the array is the new complete list, so you may have to add/remove/edit elements in the persisted array)

Comment: I changed jQuery your way, added a loop (see edit above), and everything seems to be stored in database, but how to fetch it to frontend?

Comment: If you are saving the array as post meta, you can also retrieve it with get_post_meta function call. Work in small steps and debug each step to understand what you are getting.

Comment: I didn't use post_meta. I noticed, that array I created is stored in database as 'test_testbutton' option (I checked it in php myAdmin), so I created simple 'foreach' loop to retreive it in desired location on my website. Now I need to do some more complicated operations with it :) Thanks for all help :)