# How do I build, save and retrieve wp_options from a single form in a plugin development

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working in a simple WP plugin, my first one, and I don't know the right way to handle `wp_options` table using `update_options` function. I have this code in my plugin:

```
<form name="frequent_traveler_form" method="post" action="<?php echo str_replace('%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="frequent_traveler_hidden" value="Y">
    <?php echo "<h4>" . __('Common Settings') . "</h4>"; ?>
    <p><?php _e("Default Conversion Value: "); ?><input type="text" name="ft_default" value="<?php echo $ft_default; ?>" size="5"></p>
    <p><?php _e("From Date: "); ?><input type="text" id="frequent_traveler_from_date" name="frequent_traveler_from_date" value="<?php echo $frequent_traveler_from_date ?>" class="datepicker" /></p>
    <p><?php _e("To Date: "); ?><input type="text" id="frequent_traveler_to_date" name="frequent_traveler_to_date" value="<?php echo $frequent_traveler_to_date; ?>" class="datepicker" /></p>
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="<?php _e('Save') ?>" />
    </p>
</form>
```

What I need to do is "always", add new values to some config option at `wp_options` so any time I load the plugin config I should able to create as many options as I want using the same form. This is what I did and I'm not tested yet:

```
if ($_POST['ft_default'] && $_POST['frequent_traveler_from_date'] && $_POST['frequent_traveler_to_date'] && $_POST['ft_default'] != "" && $_POST['frequent_traveler_from_date'] != "" && $_POST['frequent_traveler_to_date'] != "") {
                $ft_options = array(
                    'ft_default' => $_POST['ft_default'],
                    'frequent_traveler_from_date' => $_POST['frequent_traveler_from_date'],
                    'frequent_traveler_to_date' => $_POST['frequent_traveler_to_date']
                );
                update_option('ft_options', $ft_options);
            }
```

Is that right? How I do that?

**UPDATE**

This is what I have in `frequent-traveler.php` (the main plugin file) among other functions:

```
function frequent_traveler_admin_actions()
{
    add_options_page("Frequent Traveler Configuration", "Frequent Traveler Config", 'manage_options', "ftconfig", "frequent_traveler_admin");
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'frequent_traveler_admin_actions');

function frequent_traveler_admin()
{
    include('ft_admin.php');
}
```

And this is the code at `ft_admin.php` :

```
<?php
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');

?>

<div class="wrap">
    <?php echo "<h2>" . __('Frequent Traveler Configuration') . "</h2>"; ?>
    <form name="frequent_traveler_form" method="post" action="<?php echo str_replace('%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="frequent_traveler_hidden" value="Y">
        <?php echo "<h4>" . __('Common Settings') . "</h4>"; ?>
        <p><?php _e("Default Conversion Value: "); ?><input type="text" name="ft_default" value="<?php echo $ft_default; ?>" size="5"> 
            <?php _e("From Date: "); ?><input type="text" id="frequent_traveler_from_date" name="frequent_traveler_from_date" value="<?php echo $frequent_traveler_from_date ?>" class="datepicker" />
        <?php _e("To Date: "); ?><input type="text" id="frequent_traveler_to_date" name="frequent_traveler_to_date" value="<?php echo $frequent_traveler_to_date; ?>" class="datepicker" /></p>
        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="<?php _e('Save') ?>" />
        </p>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <table class="widefat">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Conversion Value</td>
                <td>From Date</td>
                <td>To Date</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>Conversion Value</td>
                <td>From Date</td>
                <td>To Date</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            global $wpdb;

            if ($_POST['ft_default'] && $_POST['frequent_traveler_from_date'] && $_POST['frequent_traveler_to_date'] && $_POST['ft_default'] != "" && $_POST['frequent_traveler_from_date'] != "" && $_POST['frequent_traveler_to_date'] != "") {
                $ft_options = array(
                    'ft_default' => $_POST['ft_default'],
                    'frequent_traveler_from_date' => $_POST['frequent_traveler_from_date'],
                    'frequent_traveler_to_date' => $_POST['frequent_traveler_to_date']
                );
                update_option('ft_options', $ft_options);
            }

            $config_options = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "options");
            foreach ($config_options as $cop) {

                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $cop->ft_default ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $cop->from_date ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $cop->to_date ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried [this gist](https://gist.github.com/da1nonly/2057532) code by writing the code at `ft_admin.php` top just below `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style` calls and this is what doesn't work, what I did wrong?

**UPDATE 2**

I've added this code to `ft_admin.php` file:

```
<?php
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');

add_action('admin_init', 'add_meta_boxes', 1);

function add_meta_boxes()
{
    add_meta_box('repeatable-fields', 'Promotions', 'repeatable_meta_box_display');
}

function repeatable_meta_box_display()
{
    echo "I'm here";    
}
```

And nothing is showed, what is wrong in that code?

Comment: Do you mean [repeatable fields](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14539777/1287812)?

Comment: @brasofilo where I should write this code? I put in the plugin file and didn't work

Comment: There's not enough info to diagnose what's your problem.

Comment: @brasofilo see my edit, I added relevant info

Comment: That `wpdb` seems unnecessary, search for examples [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2badmin_menu%20%2bupdate_option%20is%3aanswer) and check [this for repeatable fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445904/adding-custom-image-fields-and-other-fields-at-the-same-time).

Comment: @brasofilo I'm newbie in WP world and this is my first plugin, I read all the docs you suggest me but I'm having problem understand how I do this, could be much to ask for a little example at least for one field and using my code?

Comment: @brasofilo I'm still playing with the Gist code without success can you take a look?